# Cleanup files when using NServiceBus FileShareDataBus

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I am using the FileShareDataBus in NServiceBus 3.  Is there any support for cleaning up databus files?

If not, what would be the best practice to achieve this (like how do you ensure that the file is not part of a message that is in the error queue)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that it's impossible to know how long a message stay in the error queue I usually purge after a resonably long time (Max(SLA) + x days)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Following on from that, I presume that there is no way to detect whether a message has been fully handled by the bus? That is, all handlers and sagas completed without errors.

Comment: Its hard but I guess you can monitor the audit queue and use that to figure out when its safe to delete the data