# Cleanup files when using NServiceBus FileShareDataBus

Tags: nservicebus

My question is kind of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642468/cleanup-files-when-using-nservicebus-filesharedatabus) but I think the response is not answering the question at all.

To elaborate,
I have the following code piece:

Configuration:

```
    BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
    busConfiguration.EndpointName("Samples.DataBus.Sender");
    busConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
    busConfiguration.UseDataBus<FileShareDataBus>().BasePath(BasePath);
    busConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
    busConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
    using (IBus bus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration).Start())
    ....
```

Message:

```
[TimeToBeReceived("00:01:00")]
public class MessageWithLargePayload : ICommand
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public DataBusProperty<byte[]> LargeBlob { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine (it creates queues, sends messages in the queue, creates a file for the LargeBlob property and stores it in the base path, receiver takes the message and handles it).

My question is: Is there any way to remove the created files (LargeBlob) after the message has been handled or taken out of the queue or after it lands in the error-queue.

The [Documentation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/databus#databus-attachments-cleanup) clearly states that files are not cleaned up, but I think this is kind of a messy behaviour, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to remove the files after the message has been handled or taken out of the queue or after it lands in the error-queue.

1. After message handled
2. After taken out of the queue
3. After it is in error queue

I'm not really sure what you're after? You want to remove the files, but you're not sure when?

NServiceBus has no way to figure out when the file should be deleted. Perhaps you're deferring a message for the file to be processed later. Or you're giving the task to another handler. Which means that if the file is removed, there's no way that other handler can process the file. So removing the file depends on your functional needs.

When the message is in the error queue, it is most likely that you want to try and process it again. Why else put the message in an error queue, instead of just removing the message altogether?

Besides that, the file system isn't transactional. So there's no way for any software to tell if messages got processed correctly and the file should be deleted. And when the outbox has been enabled in NServiceBus, the message is removed from the queuing storage, but it's not been processed yet. If the file would've been removed by then, it also can't be processed anymore.

As you can tell, there are a large number of scenarios where removing the file can pose a problem. The only one who actually knows when which file could be removed, is you as a developer. You'll have to come up with a strategy to remove the files.

---

The [sample](http://docs.particular.net/samples/databus/) has a class `Program` with a static field `BasePath`. Make it public so your handler can access it. Then in the handler you can obtain the file location like this:

```
public void Handle(MessageWithLargePayload message)
{
    var filename = Path.Combine(Program.BasePath, message.LargeBlob.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(filename);
```

**UPDATE**
Added some documentation about a possible cleanup strategy. We have some plans for a really good solution, but it'll take time. So for now perhaps [this can help](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/databus#databus-attachments-cleanup-filesharedatabus).

Comment: "You'll have to come up with a strategy to remove the files." -> well, ok. The question is how? As I can see it, you have not control whatsoever, how the file nservicebus is creating is named or where it is stored (which subdirectory). The only thing I could think of is: periodically emptying the base directory, which seems hack-ish. ?

Comment: Depending on the use case, you can have the handler execute an action to remove the files. Or you can send another message to a second handler to remove the file. Because then you take the deleting of the file (which is non-transactional) outside of the original transaction. So the file is processed, everything is stored inside a database and the transaction is committed. Depending on your situation and whether or not you're using outbox, all inside transaction. Then file deletion only occurs when file is really processed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does.I get, what you are telling me (I think :-) ) and it all makes sense. My remaining question is a technical one: How do I delete the file, when I don't know which file I have to delete? As far as I understood, NServiceBus creates a file in a Timestamp-Directory that has a guid as the name. How do I know which file corresponds to which message?

Comment: I've edited the original answer to include a code sample on how to obtain the file location. Does that work for you?

Comment: *facepalm*, I could have found *that* by myself ^^. Thanks for the conceptual explanations and the code. It helped a lot.

Comment: No problem & good luck. Please remember that the sample uses TimeToBeReceived and MSMQ will remove the message itself. Result is that file will never be removed by you or whoever takes care of this : http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/discard-old-messages#caveats-msmq-transport

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link at the bottom with a hint for a cleanup strategy. Perhaps it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the file cleanup challenge by creating a service that removes the files after a configurable number of hours.  I will say that with a large number of bus files, you will be more successful if you do a rolling delete vs trying to do it once a day.

There are two options out on GitHub that are already coded that can be used:

- PowerShell Script:
  https://gist.github.com/smartindale/50674db76bd2e36cc94f
- Windows Service: https://github.com/bradjolicoeur/VapoDataBus

The PowerShell script worked with low volumes, but I had issues with running reliably with larger volumes of files.

The Windows Service is reliable on large volumes and is more efficient.